# Getting Nginx HttpSecureLinkModule 403's working

Tags: nginx, download, php

I'm trying to get a broken(?) script for video working, I'm having problems getting 403's to return if the direct link is used rather than the expire link.

I can currently get URL's secured/hidden and with expiry like this;
    domain.org/media/**X2lkdmFSZHZ1MU40dmhnM3E0V2lNQQ,1370948784**/flv/38.flv

Files are under /home/srv/public_html/media/videos/flv

But, the video files are directly available from the URL if you know the right path still;
    domain.org/media/**vidoes**/flv/38.flv

Below are the relevant section of code creating the secure link and providing progressive streaming for flv files.

```
$config['nginx_key'] = 'TOPSECRET';
$config['nginx_prefix'] = '/media/';

$file_sd = '/flv/' .$video_id. '.flv';
$time = time()+ 3600;
$md5hash_sd = md5($time . '.' . $file_sd .'.' . $config['nginx_key'], true);
$md5hash_sd = str_replace('=', '', strtr(base64_encode($md5hash_sd), '+/', '-_'));

// return result
$SD_URL = $config['BASE_URL'].$config['nginx_prefix']. $md5hash_sd . ',' .$time .$file_sd;

result; domain.org/media/X2lkdmFSZHZ1MU40dmhnM3E0V2lNQQ,1370948784/hd/38.mp4
```

These are the nginx rules;

```
location ~ ^/media/(?<secure>[\w\-=]+,\d+)(?<file>/.*\.flv)$ {
secure_link $secure;
secure_link_md5 $secure_link_expires.$file.TOPSECRET;
if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
alias  /home/srv/public_html/media/videos$file;
flv;
}
```

My question is, can someone see here how I can't return a 403 if someone tries to access the flv file directly rather than the secure link that will eventually expire.
The 403's are the only part that don't seem to be working.

Thanks for your time.
- D.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location ~ /media/(.+)\.flv$ {
root /srv/www/public_html;
deny all;
}
```

This blocks direct links to any .flv file, while allowing the script to generate hashed a URL as normal.

/media/Q9nb0mU7vLxkpR55GXehnA,1371541450/flv/37.flv - okay

/media/path/to/flv/37.flv - denied 403.

Answer (score 1):

```
    location /media/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }
```

Add this.

Comment: This only denies the directory access, not the URL to the file itself.